# Send zombie_id when coming from Zombie#show to Tweet#new (one-to-many relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models, Zombie and Tweet.  Schema below:

```
  create_table "tweets", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "zombie_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "zombies", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "graveyard"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

With the following associations:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tweets
end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :zombie
end
```

In the Zombie#show view, I have added a "New Tweet" button sending it to Tweet#new  (new_tweet_path).  In the Tweet#new view I have a form with two fields: status and zombie_id.  When I arrive at the Tweet#new page coming from a Zombie's profile, I don't want to have to fill in the zombie_id, or I'd like it to know what the id is since I just came from it's profile on the previous page.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?  I'm assuming I need to send the zombie object from the Zombie#show page to the Tweet#new page, but I'm not sure what I need to do in the controller or views to handle this.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In the Zombie#show view add zombie_id param to the `new_tweet_path` call like this:

```
new_tweet_path(zombie_id: @zombie.id)
```

Then in the Tweet#new create a Tweet model with already filled zombie_id, that was passed in params hash:

```
@tweet = Tweet.new(zombie_id: params[:zombie_id])
```